# wordpress post query argument to query child posts

Tags: wordpress

I want to query posts that are not parent ones.
Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3
Post 4
- Post 5
Post 6
So it should display only Post 2, post 3, post 5
This code only display parent one, how should it look to query all child posts

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'drama', 
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'post_parent' => 0 
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you using `WP_Query` 2 times to list it. Please consider this code

```html
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'drama', 'paged' => $paged, 'post_parent' => 0 ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
       <?php $parent_id = get_the_ID();     
         $child_query= new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'drama', 'post_parent' => $parent_id ) );     
         if ( $child_query->have_posts() ) :
          while ( $child_query->have_posts() ) : $child_query->the_post(); 
           //show post
          endwhile;
         endif;
         wp_reset_postdata();
       ?>   
    <?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is rather expensive to run. Also, with example above you are running 4 queries, not 2

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run 2 queries, but we need to be smart here as it can become quite expensive, specially if you start using multiple queries through a foreach loop.

Here is what we will do:

- Run our first query to collect **only** the page ID's of the top level pages. This will be very lean query as we will not return any other unnecessary postdata from the pages, except their ID's
- We will run the second query and simply exclude (*`post__not_in`*) the top level pages which will be an array of ID's we got from the first query

Here is it all in code

```
// Get all parent pages to exclude
$args1 = [
    'post_type'   => 'drama',
    'post_parent' => 0, // Only return top level pages
    'nopaging'    => true, // Alias of posts_per_page => -1, Get all top level pages  
    'fields'       => 'ids' // Only get pages ID's for performance
];
$exclude_parents = get_posts( $args1 );

// Now we can run our query as normal
$args = [
    'post_type'    => 'drama',
    'post__not_in' => $excluse_parents, // Exclude parent pages
    'paged'        => $paged,
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Run your loop as normal
```